# Jupyter notebook does not reload boost python module

Tags: python, c++, boost, ipython, python-import

I have a boost python module foo.so that calls c++ functions underneath. The foo.so and foo.ipynb are in the same location and

```
import foo
foo.Hello()
```

works just fine. However, if I make some changes in the c++ code and then do

```
reload(foo)
foo.Hello()
```

It is still using the old code. However, it works if I put everything in a .py file.

I have also tried

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

and the issue remains.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/487718/3962537) it's at the least tricky to reload modules implemented as extension. You might have to restart the interpreter to see any changes.

Comment: Autoreload will not try to reload extension modules, as far as I know. I consider reloading an option only for pure Python modules.